# How to display json data in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, mysql, json

I want to display data from Mysql database in Recyclerview i use this codes but i get white page nothing show i don't know where error please help me to find error please explain your answer because i'm new in android this my codes

> Mainactivity.java

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
ArrayList<listitem_gib> rewayaList = new ArrayList<>();

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

ProgressBar progressBar;
LinearLayout progress_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardview);

    TextView progress_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress_txt);
    progress_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    String url = "http://grassyhat.com/android/arabic.php";

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    progress_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("all");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = respons.getString("id");
                            String name = respons.getString("name");
                            String img = respons.getString("img");
                            String url = respons.getString("url");
                            String num = respons.getString("num");
                            String size = respons.getString("size");
                            rewayaList.add(new listitem_gib(id, name, img, url, num, size));

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
        }
    }

    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    //Just your list of objects, in your case the list that comes from the db
    CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter(rewayaList, this);

    //RecyclerView needs a layout manager in order to display data so here we create one
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //Here we set the layout manager and the adapter to the listview
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

> Adapter

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

private List<listitem_gib> rewayaList;


Context context;


public CardAdapter(List<listitem_gib> rewayaList, Context context) {

    super();

    this.rewayaList = rewayaList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, parent, false);

    CardViewHolder viewHolder = new CardViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Here you bind your views with the data from each object from the list

    listitem_gib rewaya = rewayaList.get(position);
    holder.rewaya_name.setText(rewaya.name);
    holder.writer_name.setText(rewaya.num);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rewayaList.size();
}

public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView Image;
    public TextView rewaya_name, writer_name;

    public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        rewaya_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Main_Text);
        writer_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Second_Text);
    }
}}
```

> ListItem

```
public class listitem_gib {

public String id;
public String name;
public String img;
public String url;
public String num;
public String size;

public listitem_gib(String id, String name, String img, String url, String num, String size) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.img = img;
    this.url = url;
    this.num = num;
    this.size = size;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is hard to look to your code in figure out the error 
in this cases you have to break down you code and test every part alone
first check that the response is coming form the server properly by print the response via LOG or toast then check the parsing part when you have  arrayLst 
then populate the data to the recycler view

Answer (score 1):

After

```
rewayaList.add(new listitem_gib(id, name, img, url, num, size));
```

Add

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For detailed explanation visit [Official Documentation for the function notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). It's just a few sentences so don't be scared that it might be a lengthy documentation.